# Can I force Google Chrome to cache as much as possible?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet, cache

I'm playing a game in my browser made with Unity. Before it can start, the game has to download **everything**, which sometimes takes several minutes.

Is there a way for me to force Google Chrome to be **really aggressive** in how much and which data it caches? No mater what terms I use, anything I try to find on Google only tells me how to clear the cache, not how to make it more greedy.

Comment: Even if you do increase the cache it doesn’t mean the game will respect the cache when it attempts to initialize. Often developers will purposely take a one time performance hit, to ensure the assets required do exist

Comment: Using something like --disk-cache-size=1073741824 should significantly increase it